# datatables auto pagination not displaying the correct number of rows and not resetting the row counter

Tags: jquery, datatables

The script below returns multiple rows of data which are then displayed on screen using dataTables.
The issue I have is two fold, firstly the number of rows to display is set to two (2) but
when the script runs it display all the rows. Secondly the script is not resetting the "currentInt" to the first page.

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
var imagepath = "../../../../../../";
var table = $('#glafids').DataTable( {   
        pageLength: 2, // SET NUMBER OD ROWS TO DISPLAY
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        ordering: false,
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        scrollCollapse: true,
  ajax: {
      url: 'get_fids.php', 
      dataSrc: '',
   },
    language: {
      "emptyTable": "There are no more departures for <?php echo $date; ?>"
    },
    columns: [
      { data: "Image", width: '10%', render : function (data, type){
        if (data === "") {
        return '<img src="' + noimage + '"/>';
        } else {
        return '<img src="' + imagepath + '' +data+'" />';
        }
       }
      },
     { data: "ScheduleTime", width: '10%' },
     { data: "AirportName",  width: '38%'},
     { data: "Flight",  width: '12%'},
     { data: "Terminal",  width: '12%'},
     { data: "RemarksWithTime",  width: '12%'}
     ],
     /// rowCallback: function(row, data){ 
      
   //},
  });
  // Get the page info, so we know what the last is
  
  var pageInfo = table.page.info(),
    
      // Set the ending interval to the last page
      endInt = pageInfo.end,
      
      // Current page
      currentInt = 0,
  
      // Start an interval to go to the "next" page every 3 seconds
      interval = setInterval(function(){
      // "Next" ...
      table.page( currentInt ).draw( 'page' );
    
      // Increment the current page int
      currentInt++;
      
      // If were on the last page, reset the currentInt to the first page #
      if ( currentInt ===  endInt)
        currentInt = 0;
 
      }, 3000); // 3 seconds
      
      
//console.log("INFO",pageInfo );      
});
```

Comment: First problem: `paging: false,` overrides `pageLength: 2`. Second problem: I cannot recreate - your code works fine for me (it returns to page 1). The only thing I would say is: That page manipulation code should be in an `initComplete` function, so it won't start trying to page until the table has finished being initialized.

Comment: @andrewjames Hi and many thanks for your reply. I have taken out the "paging : false" and that part is now working. well spotted. I will work on the "initComplete " part.